# Compare Nodes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am a new bee to xslt, I do not how to handle the case when one node is one level deeper 
than another node like below image. I want to compare these two values.

[image]

```
 <xsl:variable name="CURRENT_HEADING_ID">
      <xsl:if test="HEADING_ID[.!='']">
            <xsl:value-of select="HEADING_ID" />
      </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="HEADING_ROW[HEADING_ID = $CURRENT_HEADING_ID]">

do something

</xsl:for-each>
```

Here I cannot describe the whole picture but if my Current_Heading_ID matches with HEADING_ID than I want to move on with this foreach else ...

My XML looks like---

```
<HEADING_ROW Sort="1">
        <HEADING_ID>10051</HEADING_ID>
        <HEADING_NAME>HEADING 1</HEADING_NAME>
        <HEADING_DESCRIPTION/>
</HEADING_ROW>
<HEADING_ROW Sort="2">
        <HEADING_ID>10050</HEADING_ID>
        <HEADING_NAME>HEADING 2</HEADING_NAME>
        <HEADING_DESCRIPTION>HEADING 2 Descp</HEADING_DESCRIPTION>
</HEADING_ROW>
```

I know it is a very dumb question, but I am in a kind of a hurry and stuck to that issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  You already have the right syntax for a `for-each` over all the `HEADING_ROW` elements that match `$CURRENT_HEADING_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this because you are currently positioned on a **HEADING_ROW** element, and want to get the other **HEADING_ROW** elements with the same HEADING_ID?

If so, try this

```
<xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::HEADING_ROW[HEADING_ID = $CURRENT_HEADING_ID]">
```

Or maybe this (which would get all siblings, but also the current HEADING_ROW too)

```
<xsl:for-each select="../HEADING_ROW[HEADING_ID = $CURRENT_HEADING_ID]">
```